# Touch Bug in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I made following application (as a test)

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="GUITest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Text="openDialog" Background="Red"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(dlg.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

I catch the mouseDown event because it catches both mouse button down events and touch down events. The code has the expected behavior for mouse clicks. Touch gives me some trouble.

If i touch the TextBlock it opens a dialog window as asked. after closing it, any touch on the window opens the dialog window, even if the touch was not on the TextBlock.

Is this a bug? Can i work around this?

EDIT: i posted a workaround, an actual fix would still be usefull

Comment: I have two observations - one, if you move the window, the problem stops, and two, in a real-life situation like this, you would probably want to use a button (I know this is just a test, so this is an interesting question).  Maybe this can help you come up with something.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find anything that works.

Comment: @hosch250 Thanks for the button tip. It isn't really an answer to the problem but it's a work around. I wanted the button to look like a TextBlock though, so i restyled the Button, posting my solution soon

Answer (score 0):

For other people who run into the same problem. This isn't a fix to the problem, but it is a workaround.
I used a button and restyled it to look like a TextBlock

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
   <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click" Content="openDialog">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                 <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
   </Button>
</Grid>
```

Code for Button_Click is the same as TextBlock_MouseDown